# Find and highlight word in Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook

How to find text (in this case -1.00 (some negative number) or +1.50 (some positive number) in the email body (compose part) and change font color of these words.

Comment: This site exists to allow programmers to help one another develop. It is not a site where you can post vague requirements and expect a solution.

Comment: You say "-1.00" (some negative number). Does this include "-1", "-1." and "-1.0"? Does "+1.50" include "1.5"?  Is it really only two numbers or could it be more?  Are these numbers fixed for ever, fixed for a reasonable period or do they change for every run of the macro. Are the numbers changed to the same font or different fonts. Is the font fixed or can that change. These are just a few of the obvious questions. You must complete your specification before thinking about coding. If you are not sure what you want, create a simple specification for an experiment.

Comment: Once you have your specification, break it into parts. How will the macro get the numbers?  How will the macro gets the fonts? How do you change the font of a string within an html document? Research these parts individually. There are lots of snippets out there if you look for solutions to single problems.

Comment: Save the html body as a file and amend it manually. This will give you a good indication of the structure of the code.

Comment: the issue i'm having most trouble with the part of the vba code code that finds and selects the requared text (that would be 4 characters after the "-" or "+" symbols. I can enter the specifications after that.

Answer (score 0):

Even when you reduce your question to just the editing, I am confused.  Do you really want to font the number but not the sign?  The result looks very strange to me.

I have created a subroutine that does nothing but the editing.  You can either put code around it to achieve your objective or you can pick ideas from my subroutine and incorporate them in your own routine.

The parameters of this subroutine are:

**Prefix and Text**

You could have Prefix = “+” and Text = “1.50” or Prefix = “” and Text = “+1.50”.  With the first, only the number is formatted; with the second the sign is formatted as well.  The length of these strings can be anything not just the 1 and 4 you request.

**StartFormat and EndFormat**

There are a variety of possible techniques for formatting bits of Html text but I cannot think of one that does not involve placing a start string before the text and an end string after the text.  For my testing I created a html document with some black, some red and some blue text.  I them placed “+1.50”s in each section.  The values I passed for Start Format and EndFormat were "<span style=""color:#00FF00"">" and "</span>".  The calls of EditHtml set all the “+1.50”s or all the “1.50”s green.

**Html**

This is the Html document to be amended.  It is passed “By Reference” so the original string is updated.

I hope this helps.

```
Sub EditHtml(ByVal Prefix As String, ByVal Text As String, _
             ByVal StartFormat As String, ByVal EndFormat As String, _
             ByRef Html As String)

  Dim Pos As Long

  Pos = 1

  ' Loop for each occurrence of Prefix & Text.
  Do While True
    Pos = InStr(Pos, Html, Prefix & Text)
    If Pos = 0 Then
      Exit Do
    End If

    Pos = Pos + Len(Prefix) ' Step over prefix

    ' Insert string that starts format change
    Html = Mid(Html, 1, Pos - 1) & StartFormat & Mid(Html, Pos)

    Pos = Pos + Len(StartFormat) ' Step over string that starts format change
    Pos = Pos + Len(Text)        ' Step over text whose format is to be changed

    ' Insert string that ends format change
    Html = Mid(Html, 1, Pos - 1) & EndFormat & Mid(Html, Pos)

    Pos = Pos + Len(EndFormat) ' Step over string that ends format change

  Loop

End Sub
```